# Condense TSQL statement with a double layer group by having count(*) =

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

An thoughts on how to condense this query?

```
select [gp1].[sID] 
from
( 
   select [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID], [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID]
     from [ftsIndexWordOnce] with (nolock)
     Join [FTSindex] with (nolock) 
       On [FTSindex].[sID] = [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID] 
      And [FTSindex].[wordID] = [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] 
      And [FTSindex].[wordPOS] <= '1000' 
     join [FTSwordDef] with (nolock) 
       on [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] = [FTSwordDef].[ID] 
      and [FTSwordDef].[word] in ('capital','bank')   
    group by [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID], [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID]
)   [gp1] 
group by [gp1].[sID] 
having count(*) = 2
```

PK [ftsIndexWordOnce] is [sID], [wordID]
PK [FTSindex] is [sID], [wordPos]

Below is not part of the question.
It is just background.

The base query is

```
select [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID] 
 from [ftsIndexWordOnce] with (nolock)
 join [FTSwordDef] with (nolock) 
   on [ftsIndexWordOnce].[wordID] = [FTSwordDef].[ID] 
  and [FTSwordDef].[word] in ('capital','bank')
group by [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID]
having count(*) = 2 
order by [ftsIndexWordOnce].[sID]
```

This finds document with both the words.
The question query extends this to both those words in the 1000 words.

Comment: If you're going to do `WITH (NOLOCK)` (and yes, I come down on the "don't do this" side of the debate) then you may as well just issue `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` and be done with it. It's a mess to put it on every table!!

Comment: @ErikE How can you have a debate on the use of (nolock) when you know nothing about how the application is used.

Comment: Because it can return data that never existed, not just uncommitted data. It can also cause queries to exclude rows that are already committed when using indexed views, as proven in the wild (sorry, I can't find the recent question on SO where a poster showed this was happening). Systems that require uncommitted reads to avoid deadlocks or long blocks are in my (perhaps wrong) opinion in dire need of redesign or index overhauling.

Comment: @ErikE Again you know nothing about this app.  Really a (nolock) can return data the never exited?  Just how do you return data that never existed?   I don't want to take read lock to not slow down inserts.  This data is never mutated.

Comment: I'm sorry to have stepped on your toes about `NOLOCK`. It is clearly an area you feel strongly about. I was trying to help by giving a way to clean up the queries by not having to write the table hint over and over--my "don't do this" comment was just an aside, meant mildly. About "never existed", I didn't make up that term, there are [resources on the web](http://sqlserver.itags.org/q_sql-server_54875.html) that suggest this for dirty reads. In any case, I'm glad you are well versed on the pitfalls of dirty reads and know that your application is benefited by them.

Comment: Although in your defense, I did say "never existed, not just uncommitted data" meaning I saw a difference between them. I think I was remembering an article I read once about how when you defeat locks like `READ UNCOMMITTED` does, you can end up pulling data from a data page that, at the time of the actual I/O, no longer belongs to the table in question, and in a high-concurrency environment this table could contain garbage data. But I don't have a reference and can't find this online, so my apologies if I overstated the case.

Comment: P.S. what did you mean by "buy a vowel"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most important issue is that you need indexes in both `FTSindex` and `ftsIndexWordOnce` on the `wordID` column. You didn't say if there are nonclustered indexes on these tables that have `wordID` as the first column--but even if they have such indexes, How often are individual words looked up from a known `sID`? It seems more likely to me that you are starting from particular known words and trying to find `sID`s from them. If my guess is right, then your PKs should change to put `wordID` first. `sID` can be the first column in a nonclustered index so that targeted queries based on `sID` can still use two separate seeks (once to the nonclustered, then to the clustered).

Once those indexes are in place, we can address the next thing: it seems like you're joining to `ftsIndexWordOnce` because it only indexes each word per `sID` once, but then since that table doesn't have a `firstWordPOS` column, you also have to join to `FTSindex` to make sure each word appears in the first 1000-- so this pretty much loses the entire benefit of using `ftsIndexWordOnce`. Right now, since my guess is that you would have to do a table scan on either one, `ftsIndexWordOnce` still gives you some benefit because it is a smaller table and thus takes fewer reads to scan. Once you address the index problems above, suddenly `ftsIndexWordOnce` is needlessly costing more, and you can eliminate `ftsIndexWordOnce` from the query by using `Count(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT
   i.sID
FROM
   dbo.FTSindex i
   INNER JOIN dbo.FTSwordDef w
      ON i.wordID = w.ID
WHERE
   i.wordPOS <= 1000
   AND w.word in ('capital','bank')   
GROUP BY
   i.sID
HAVING
   Count(DISTINCT i.wordID) = 2
;
```

Another idea is that you could add a `firstWordPOS` column to the `ftsIndexWordOnce`, and modify whatever process you already use to build it in the first place to update that as well (and then populate it). This would allow you to go back to your original query and simply add the condition `AND firstWordPOS <= 1000`. With the smaller size of the `ftsIndexWordOnce` table and its new clustered index starting with `wordID`, performance will be further improved.

Here is another crazy idea that might give you some benefit if you do add an index on `wordID` but don't make it the first column of the clustered indexes:

```
SELECT W1.sID
FROM
   (
      SELECT DISTINCT i.sID
      FROM
         dbo.FTSindex i
         INNER JOIN dbo.FTSwordDef w
            ON i.wordID = w.ID
      WHERE
         i.wordPOS <= 1000 
         AND w.word = 'capital'
    ) W1 INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT i.sID
      FROM
         dbo.FTSindex i
         INNER JOIN dbo.FTSwordDef w
            ON i.wordID = w.ID
      WHERE
         i.wordPOS <= 1000 
         AND w.word = 'bank'
     ) W2 ON W1.sID = W2.sID
;
```

This has the drawback of not being easily modified to accommodate more words, but may switch certain queries to range seeks from scans--sometimes `OR` or `IN` can trigger a scan, where if the number of items is small, separate queries will get seeks.

Last, since `wordPOS` is obviously numeric, please do not put it in quotes as a string in your query: `wordPOS <= 1000` is better.

P.S. Just to be clear, changing the PKs is not required. As you said, doing so might be catastrophic to the nightly load process. But you did indicate there are other indexes, so if you have one on `WordID` in those tables then perhaps you are already well served.

May I suggest humbly (since I don't know your system like you do) that if your loads mostly insert new data without changing a lot of existing data, then your system may reach a tipping point where reloading the entire set of data is slower than putting in the changes. You could even consider using a staging table that is ordered by `sID`, and from which only strategic updates are made to the final table--and if you were to do that, then changing the PK of the final table could become an option. Just a (possibly ignorant) thought.

Comment: Changing the PK is NOT an option.  When I load to that table I need to load as fast as possible and the data loads that order.  I drop other indexes, load, and then rebuild other indexes.  It is a massive table that loads at night.  As for no value in [ftsIndexWordOnce] - did you look at the "base query"?   The first query gives the right answer and I have not yet tested the second.  It gets built up into a larger query and the query optimizer can (easily) get stupid.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "no value in `ftsIndexWordOnce`". I did look at your base query. I see that you modified it to try to ensure the words appear in the first 1000 words. Since you do have additional indexes, did you try either of my queries as is?

Comment: Get it, my mistake.  Your first query does not use ftsIndexWordOnce.  This is a massive table that does not mutate.  May truncate and recreate the table but it never mutates.  And I said the first gives  the right answer.

Comment: @Blam Oh, I wasn't sure if you meant your first query or my first query.

Comment: Went with the first.  And I don't reload all data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might work:

```
 select Distinct o.sID
 from ftsIndexWordOnce o with (nolock)
    Join FTSindex i with (nolock) 
       On i.sID = o.sID 
          And i.wordID = o.wordID 
          And i.wordPOS <= '1000' 
    join FTSwordDef w with (nolock) 
       on w.ID = o.wordID
          and w.word in ('capital','bank')   
 group by o.sID
 Having Count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Good thought and worth a try but returns more records.  If capital alone occurred twice then it get included.